# Can Selenium Grid run in Jenkins with JRE 11?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, java-8, java-11

I tried installing Jenkins with JDK 11 on a Linux server, and now I'm trying to add the Selenium (Grid) plugin.

I managed to get it to work on Jenkins with JDK8, but after upgrading to JDK 11, the plugin says Accept Time out, and the setting to access the grid on the right in Jenkin's menu disappeared.

I can't find a documentation saying it isn't compatible with JDK11, as on [their page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/selenium/) it says it requires java 1.8 or later.

*Note: I also tried a fresh installation with JDK 11 directly, but I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but for those who read it later. Selenium plugin is not compatible with java 11. You have to use java 8.